# Using SED to join 2 fields in CSV and add them at the end of the line

Tags: sed

I have a SED problem beyond my knowledge. I have a solar plant that generates CSV files in the format

```
2012-01-08;00:00;171,297;0,000;    
2012-01-08;00:05;171,297;0,000;
2012-01-08;00:10;171,297;0,000;
2012-01-08;00:15;171,297;0,000;
2012-01-08;00:20;171,297;0,000;
2012-01-08;00:25;171,297;0,000;
```

I'm importing these values in a MySQL database. I would like to have a combination of the 2 first values to act as a unique primary key.

The result should look like:

```
2012-01-08;00:00;171,297;0,000;2012-01-08-00:00
2012-01-08;00:05;171,297;0,000;2012-01-08-00:05
2012-01-08;00:10;171,297;0,000;2012-01-08-00:10
2012-01-08;00:15;171,297;0,000;2012-01-08-00:15
2012-01-08;00:20;171,297;0,000;2012-01-08-00:20
```

Comment: Do you really need to do this in `sed`?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `awk` for this, not `sed`:

```
awk -F';' ' NF {print $0 $1"-"$2}'
```

Where:

- `-F';'`: defines the input field separator
- `NF`: is the number of fields, used here to filter out lines with no fields
- `$0`: is the whole line
- `$1` and `$2`: are the first and second fields
- The rest, I think, is self-explanatory.

Demo:

```
% echo '2012-01-08;00:00;171,297;0,000;

2012-01-08;00:05;171,297;0,000;

2012-01-08;00:10;171,297;0,000;

2012-01-08;00:15;171,297;0,000;

2012-01-08;00:20;171,297;0,000;

2012-01-08;00:25;171,297;0,000;' | awk -F';' ' NF {print $0 $1"-"$2}'
2012-01-08;00:00;171,297;0,000;2012-01-08-00:00
2012-01-08;00:05;171,297;0,000;2012-01-08-00:05
2012-01-08;00:10;171,297;0,000;2012-01-08-00:10
2012-01-08;00:15;171,297;0,000;2012-01-08-00:15
2012-01-08;00:20;171,297;0,000;2012-01-08-00:20
2012-01-08;00:25;171,297;0,000;2012-01-08-00:25
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(\([^;]*;\)\{2\}\)\(.*\)/\1\2\1/ ; s/;$// ; s/\(.*\);/\1-/' infile
```

Explanation:

```
s/\(\([^;]*;\)\{2\}\)\(.*\)/\1\2\1/     # Match content until second ';' and copy it at the end of the 
                                        # line.
s/;$//                                  # Delete last ';'
s/\(.*\);/\1-/                          # Substitute last ';' with '-'
```

Result:

```
2012-01-08;00:00;00:00;2012-01-08-00:00
2012-01-08;00:05;00:05;2012-01-08-00:05
2012-01-08;00:10;00:10;2012-01-08-00:10
2012-01-08;00:15;00:15;2012-01-08-00:15
2012-01-08;00:20;00:20;2012-01-08-00:20
2012-01-08;00:25;00:25;2012-01-08-00:25
```

Comment: +1: Thanks for demonstrating why I'd use `awk` ;)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed 'h;s/;.*//;H;g;s/\s*\n//' file
```